# Fetch and display sqlite data through a List Adapter in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I wish to show all the values in a database table in a list within a fragment. For this I'm using a custom list adapter to show values present in the cursor in a fragment list.

The fragment class is showing some constructor related error(which says the constructor is undefined) in my DatabaseHandler class and the adapter class.

I guess the error is due to the context variable that I've used in my Databasehandler class. And I think we need to declare some other variable type for fragments.
This will also help others in using custom list adapters and listview in a fragment as I hardly find any good tutorial over the net.

So when I create a new constructor like this is in my Handler class --

```
public  Database_Schema(Fragment_Java fragment_Java) {
        context = fragment_Java;
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
```

the editor again complains to change the type of context to fragment_java.

Here's the DatabaseHandler class I'm using in my application:

```
    package info.aea.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    // Called when no database exists in disk and the helper class needs
    // to create a new one.
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb;
    public long r;
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db)
    {
        //  _db.execSQL(LoginTable.DATABASE_CREATE);
        //  sqldb = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }
    /*  public LoginDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name,CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
}*/
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "java.db", null, 1);
        sqldb = this.getWritableDatabase();

        try {
            sqldb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists SourceCodes (CodeID text PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , " +
                    "CodeLang text NOT NULL, CodeTitle text NOT NULL , CodeSource text NOT NULL , " +
                    "CodeOutput text NOT NULL);");

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put("CodeID", "t1");
            cv.put("CodeLang", "java");
            cv.put("CodeTitle", "title1");
            cv.put("CodeSource", "source code here1");
            cv.put("CodeOutput", "output here1");

            r = sqldb.insert("SourceCodes", null, cv);

            //ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();

            cv.put("CodeID", "t2");
            cv.put("CodeLang", "java");
            cv.put("CodeTitle", "title2");
            cv.put("CodeSource", "source code here2");
            cv.put("CodeOutput", "output here2");

            r = sqldb.insert("SourceCodes", null, cv);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
}



    // Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that the version
    // of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to the current version.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion)
    {
        // Log the version upgrade.
        Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to " +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");


        // Upgrade the existing database to conform to the new version. Multiple
        // previous versions can be handled by comparing _oldVersion and _newVersion
        // values.
        // The simplest case is to drop the old table and create a new one.
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Database_Schema.DATABASE_CREATE);

        // Create a new one.
        onCreate(_db);
    }
}
```

Below is the Class defining the database schema and containing CRUD operation methods related to the table --

```
    package info.aea.database;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class Database_Schema {

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login.db";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
    // TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
    // SQL Statement to create a new database.
    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+" LOGIN "+
            "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement," + "USERNAME  char unique,PASSWORD text, USERTYPE text); ";



    // Variable to hold the database instance
    public  SQLiteDatabase db;

    // Context of the application using the database.
    private final Context context;

    // Database open/upgrade helper
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    public  Database_Schema(Context _context) {
        context = _context;
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }



    public  Database_Schema open() throws SQLException {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        db.close();
    }

    public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance(){
        return db;
    }





    //---------------------CRUD Operations---------------------//


    // get all query
    public List<SourceCode_Table> getall(String lang) {
        List<SourceCode_Table> codelist = new ArrayList<SourceCode_Table>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM SourceCodes where codelang='java'" ;    // Select All Query
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to Vector
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                SourceCode_Table a = new SourceCode_Table();

                a.setCodeID(cursor.getString(0));
                a.setCodeTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                a.setCodeSource(cursor.getString(3));
                a.setCodeOutput(cursor.getString(4));

                codelist.add(a);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return codelist;
    }
}
```

Also I wish to merge both these DB_related classes in a single DB_handler class. But it gives some weird errors or doesn't create a database if compiles without an error. Need a help in doing this also. I simply want to remove that extra class as it creates confusion while declaring DB schema and applying queries.

For the table named source codes I have made an adapter class. This is the list adapter class --

```
    package info.aea.database;

import info.devey.java.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SourceCode_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] CodeID;
    private final String[] CodeLang;
    private final String[] CodeTitle;
    private final String[] CodeSource;
    private final String[] CodeOutput;


    public SourceCode_Adapter(Context context, String[] codeid, String[] codelang, String[] codetitle, String[] codesource, String[] codeoutput) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_items, codeid);

        this.context = context;
        this.CodeID = codeid;
        this.CodeLang = codelang;
        this.CodeTitle = codetitle;
        this.CodeSource = codesource;
        this.CodeOutput = codeoutput;

    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvPat);
        String test=(" code ID: "+ CodeID[position]+ "\n code Language: "+ CodeLang[position]+ "\n Code Title: "+
                    CodeTitle[position]+ "\n code Source: "+ CodeSource[position]+ "\n code output: "+ CodeOutput[position]);
        textView.setText(test);
        System.out.println("list values ------->> " + CodeID[position] + CodeLang[position] + CodeOutput[position] + CodeSource[position] + CodeTitle[position] );
        return rowView;
    }

}
```

And finally here is the Fragment class in which I want to show the database values in a list. But When I try to instantiate a new DB object, the editor shows an error mark and suggests to change the constructor declaration and context type.

Guess all due to those poorly written database classes.

```
    package info.aea.drawer;

import info.aea.database.Database_Schema;
import info.aea.database.SourceCode_Adapter;
import info.aea.database.SourceCode_Table;
import info.devey.java.R;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Fragment_Java extends Fragment {

    String[] codeid;
    String codelang[];
    String codetitle[];
    String codesource[];
    String codeoutput[];

    ListView listview;

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Database_Schema logindb;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {       

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_java, container,false);

        logindb=new Database_Schema(this);
        logindb=logindb.open();

        String lang="java";
        List<SourceCode_Table> ls   = logindb.getall(lang);

        codeid    = new String[ls.size()];
        codelang    = new String[ls.size()];
        codetitle    = new String[ls.size()];
        codesource    = new String[ls.size()];
        codeoutput = new String[ls.size()];

        for(int i = 0; i<ls.size();i++) {
            codeid[i]= ls.get(i).getCodeID();
            codelang[i]= ls.get(i).getCodeLang();
            codetitle[i]= ls.get(i).getCodeTitle();
            codesource[i]= ls.get(i).getCodeSource();
            codeoutput[i]= ls.get(i).getCodeOutput();

            Log.v("code id","-------"+ls.get(i).getCodeID());
            Log.v("code lang","-------"+ls.get(i).getCodeLang());
            System.out.println("patname==============+++++++++++++++++++"+ codeid);
            System.out.println("date==============+++++++++++++++++++"+ codelang);
        }


        SourceCode_Adapter adapter = new SourceCode_Adapter(this, codeid, codelang, codetitle, codesource, codeoutput);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);  
          }
}
```

So need a help in rectifying these errors. I'm willing to share the whole project as an export file so as to make it simple for the debugging.

Comment: it is compile time error, just read it ... Fragment it is not Context ... Activity is ... how to get Activity in Fragment? ... do some reaserch

Comment: So, you copy/pasted code you don't understand, and you get an error. Well, this is the perfect moment to realize you're not going to become a developer just by copy/pasting ...

Comment: oh yes a compile time error. And I'm researching and reading since yesterday. :)

Comment: Don't know what made you think so. I simply reused the google's navigation drawer code. Now what's bad in copy/pasting ?

Comment: "Now what's bad in copy/pasting?" ... nothing ... if you understand the code :)

Comment: Found out where I was wrong. The fragment needs a Fragment context not an activity context.
Replaced 
    
logindb=new Database_Schema(this);
  //logindb=logindb.open();

with 

logindb = new Database_Schema(getActivity()); 
        logindb = logindb.open();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I found out where I was wrong. I was passing a context which is meant for activities to a fragment. The fragment needs a Fragment context and not an activity context. 
getActivity() is used to pass a context to a fragment, which returns the activity associated with a fragment.

If your activity class extends Activity, you can get application context using getApplicatoinContext(). But this method won’t be available when your Activity extends from Fragment.
When your activity extends Fragment, use getActivity() to get the context of the activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting application context
        Context context = getActivity();
    }
}
```

So I replaced

```
logindb=new Database_Schema(this); 
   logindb=logindb.open();
```

with

```
 logindb = new Database_Schema(getActivity()); 
    logindb = logindb.open()
```